# Performance of XSL while creating CSV from XML

Tags: xslt, sas

i am trying to process 8 XML in parallel using PROC XSL .
Each XML is of different structure and complex hierarchical path.Am trying to create CSV out of each XML.

The XSLT sheet that i created is using XSD that was provided for the XML .but the actual XML file doesnt have values for all the columns specified in the XSD and some columns doesnt come in the XML at all .

For Example : based on the XSD we expect the XML to be like the one below

```
  <Master2>
   <Child1>
      <tag1>name1</tag1>
      <tag2>name2</tag2>
      <TypeArray>
         <value>1</value>
         <value>13</value>
      </TypeArray>  
      <TypeArray1>
         <Quanutityvalue>1</Quanutityvalue>
         <Qualityvalue>13</Qualityvalue>
      </TypeArray1>     
  </Child1>
</Master2>
```

But what we receive as below

```
<Master2>
   <Child1>
      <tag1>name1</tag1>
      <TypeArray>
         <value>1</value>
         <value>13</value>
      </TypeArray>    
  </Child1>
</Master2>
```

When we create XSLT we create with all columns .The XML that we receive have data for multiple table in it .we create 4 csv from the each of the XML .and each CSV have around 270 columns.
The total time taken to process 8 files is 3 minute 50 seconds .

Does the XSL takes more time to read the NULL tags as well ? or is the time justifiable?
Am using PROC XSL option in SAS

Sample XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="/"> 
  <xsl:text>tag1,tag2,TypeArray,Quanutityvalue,Qualityvalue</xsl:text> 
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text> 
     <xsl:for-each select="Master1/Master2/Child1">
         <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize- 
          space(tag1)"/></xsl:call-template>
         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
         <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize- 
          space(tag2)"/></xsl:call-template>
         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="TypeArray/value"/> 
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="TypeArray1/Quanutityvalue"/> 
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="TypeArray1/Qualityvalue"/> 
       <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

</xsl:template>

Thanks

Comment: How big are the files? 3m 50s seems very slow unless they are multi-gigabyte. (Note, I think you're using a very old XSLT processor and you're unlikely to find anyone here who knows it well enough to help you with detailed performance questions. Measure and compare.)

Comment: Given [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66351355/proc-groovy-to-parse-larger-xml-into-sas), probably very large.

Comment: yes its big ,am just finding around some way to read the XML